# Plotly express animations: Plotting multiple changing traces and background image for each frame

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, plotly-express

I am currently trying to create a debugging tool for a simulation. For this is am working with the animations of plotly express. What I want to achieve:
An animation with a different background image with different traces (also differing in number) for each frame. Any help would be very much appreciated! (Also if someone knows how to do this using any other library it'd be very much appreciated!)

Thanks!

Adding the background images work perfectly well like this:

```
fig = px.imshow(img,origin="upper", animation_frame=0, binary_string=True, labels=dict(animation_frame="slice"))
```

So I only need to figure out how to display the traces.
I tried the following first:

```
fig = px.imshow(img,origin="upper", animation_frame=0, binary_string=True, labels=dict(animation_frame="slice")) # img consists of |time_step| images (np.array) 

## now I'm trying to add the traces 

for i in range(len(img)):
    time_step = df.iloc[i]
    for j in range(len(time_step)):                            
        current = time_step.iloc[j]
        x, y = current["x"], current["y"]  

        if (not current["valid"]):
            fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, name="{}".format(current["unique_id"]),                         text="{}".format(current["costs"]), hoverinfo='text+name', line=dict(color="black", dash="dot"), line_shape="spline"))
        else:
            fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=x_list, y=y_list, line=dict(color="black"), line_shape="spline"))
fig.show()
```

However, I realized that fig.add_trace always adds the trace to all frames of the animation. (When only displaying the first time step it worked though :) )
However, I'd like to add the traces for one time_step only and then the ones for the next time_step.
So I started looking into this approach:

```
# saving in a list instead of printing immediately
        if (not current["feasible"]):
            info.append([x_list, y_list, "{}".format(current["unique_id"]),
                        "{}".format(current["costs"]), dict(color=color, dash="dot")])
                        
        else:
            info.append([x_list, y_list, "{}".format(current["unique_id"]),
                        "{}".format(current["costs"]),dict(color=color)])
```

and added the information to the single frames:

```
    frames.append(
        go.Frame(
                data=[go.Scatter(
                        x=information[0],
                        y=information[1],
                        name=information[2],
                        text=information[3],
                        hoverinfo='text+name',
                        line=information[4],
                        line_shape="spline"
                    )
                for information in info],
            )
            
        )

figa = go.Figure(data=fig.data, frames=frames, layout=fig.layout)
figa.show()
```

But it only displays the first background image and once I start the animation it disappears and only shows the first saved Scatter for each time_step.

I'm a little lost as I don't have a set number of traces I can't "hardcode" the Scatters.